# Can't recolor edges in vtk

Tags: c++, vtk

I have an unstructured grid in VTK which I want to render along with it's edge lines. I am able to do this using `vtkExtractEdges`, however, the edge lines are always colored blue, no matter what I do.
I have working code which draws the outlines of the grid perfectly fine in my desired color, and I tried using essentially the same code for edges:

```
vtkSmartPointer<vtkOutlineFilter> outline = vtkSmartPointer<vtkOutlineFilter>::New();
vtkSmartPointer<vtkPolyDataMapper> outline_mapper = vtkSmartPointer<vtkPolyDataMapper>::New();
vtkSmartPointer<vtkActor> outline_actor = vtkSmartPointer<vtkActor>::New();

outline->SetInput(grid);
outline_mapper->SetInputConnection(outline->GetOutputPort());
outline_actor->SetMapper(outline_mapper);
outline_actor->GetProperty()->SetColor(1.,1.,1.); // << works just fine here
renderer->AddActor(outline_actor);

vtkSmartPointer<vtkExtractEdges> edges = vtkSmartPointer<vtkExtractEdges>::New();
vtkSmartPointer<vtkPolyDataMapper> edges_mapper = vtkSmartPointer<vtkPolyDataMapper>::New();
vtkSmartPointer<vtkActor> edges_actor = vtkSmartPointer<vtkActor>::New();

edges_mapper->SetInputConnection(edges->GetOutputPort());
edges_actor->SetMapper(edges_mapper);
edges_actor->GetProperty()->SetColor(1.,1.,1.); // << still stays blue here
renderer->AddActor(edges_actor);
```

This puzzles, especially since the class I call `SetColor` on is `vtkPolyDataMapper`, and after this, the code is identical for both cases.

Has anybody else experienced this problem and knows a solution?
So far, I found this: https://public.kitware.com/pipermail/vtkusers/1999-September/087677.html, in which somebody proposed solving it by drawing tubes, but I hope for a clean solution instead.

The VTK version I work with is 5.6 and I can't use a different one for reasons of compatibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question:

I found out that the data produced by `vtkPolyDataMapper` when being fed a `vtkExtractEdges` has scalar values (based on the incident cells I suppose) and the lines are colored by a lookup table, not as a single color.
Therefore, all I needed to do was to give the mapper a mono-colored lookup table. The new code is now

```
    edges_mapper->SetInputConnection(edges->GetOutputPort());
    edges_mapper->SetLookupTable(build_mono_table(1.,1.,1.));
    edges_actor->SetMapper(edges_mapper);
    renderer->AddActor(edges_actor);
```

with a helper function

```
inline vtkSmartPointer<vtkLookupTable> build_mono_table(double r, double g, double b)
{
    vtkSmartPointer<vtkLookupTable> table = vtkSmartPointer<vtkLookupTable>::New();
    table->SetNumberOfTableValues(1);
    table->Build();
    table->SetTableValue(0, r, g, b);
    return table;
}
```

There seems to be no need to specify the scalar range.